# Delete all records from a table except latest N months records (sorted by id)

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anyone please help me in solving this. Only I need is to keep the latest 3 months records in table.

Table Structure:

[image]

After Purge my table should look like this

[image]

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Im receiving following Error
'Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.'

Comment: On [Micorsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx) `ALL` is used with "a scalar value with a single-column set of values." Note where it says single-column. Your error message says it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE
    FROM Tablex 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(InsertDt ) LastDate, id FROM Tablex  GROUP by id) LastDates ON LastDates.id = Tablex.id
    WHERE InsertDt < dateadd(m,-3,LastDates.LastDate)
```

Comment: DELETE Tablex FROM Tablex  INNER JOIN (SELECT max(InsertDt ) LastDate, id FROM Tablex  GROUP by id) LastDates
ON LastDates.id = Tablex.id WHERE InsertDt < dateadd(m,-3,LastDates.LastDate)

Its working,Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear but if you mean that you want to delete records older than 3 months you should do this:

```
DELETE from Tablex 
    WHERE datediff(m,InsertDt , getdate())> 3
```

Comment: I want to delete records older than latest 3 month for each id in table not for single id